# How to populate one of 52 sheets with data straight out of Userform without "master sheet"

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm looking for a solution to a problem of populating data from Userform across different sheets based on what is stated in Userform. I have 52 weeks sheets that look exactly the same[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAKnM.jpg), Userform [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r74qg.png) and a sheet that could work as reference tables sheet[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pNda.jpg) (in pic no 3 - red table is a reference of a sheet a macro would open (so if someone inserts date 5.01.2021 it would open sheet named "Week 2"), green table is a reference of row number of each day and person (so if Mike would like to insert his data on 5.01.2021, macro knows it's Tuesday and it's Mike, so it choses row no 72 to populate), and blue table is a reference of columns numbers or letters (so macro would choose proper column to put data in).

Userform elements are:

Name - cmbImieiNazwisko

Date - cmbData

NDS - txtNDS

Over - TxtOver

Less - txtLess

CMP - txtCMP

RTN - txtRTN

Support NDS - txtSupportNDS

Support Matching - txtSupportMatching

Support Hrs - txtSupportHRS

Accept and insert data - cmdAkceptuj

Clear the form - cmdWyczysc

Exit form - cmdWyjdz

I would like to avoid having to put these info in table and then transferring data to proper week sheets. The best option is just to copy and paste data from user form to proper cell in week sheets, so if someone would like to make correction, data would just be overwritten.

Thanks in advance for replies :)
[image: Week sheets]
[image: User form]
[image: reference tables]

What I have right now is (and I know it's just scrap, but don't know what to do next):

```
Sub PopSheets()

Dim Name As String
Dim Data As String
Dim dRow As Long
Dim nRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim day As String
Dim rNo As String
Dim wkday As Long
Dim NDScell As Range
Dim Overcell As Range
Dim Lesscell As Range
Dim CMPcell As Range
Dim RTNcell As Range
Dim SupportNDScell As Range
Dim SupportMatchingcell As Range
Dim SupportHRScell As Range
Dim NDS As String
Dim Over As String
Dim Less As String
Dim CMP As String
Dim RTN As String
Dim SupportNDS As String
Dim SupportMatching As String
Dim SupportHRS As String
Dim datesheet As Range
Dim namesheet As Range
Dim weekday As Range

datesheet = Sheets("Weeksdates").Range("C2:C366")
namesheet = Sheets("Weeksdates").Range("G2:G31")
weekday = Sheets("Weeksdates").Range("H1:N1")
Data = UserForm1.cmbData
Name = UserForm1.cmbImieiNazwisko
sht = Cells(dRow, 1)
day = Cells(dRow, 2)
dRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Data, datesheet, 0)
nRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Name, namesheet, 0)
wkday = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(day, weekday, 0)

If wkday = 1 Then
    rNo = Cells(nRow, 8).Value
ElseIf wkday = 2 Then
    rNo = Cells(nRow, 9).Value
ElseIf wkday = 3 Then
    rNo = Cells(nRow, 10).Value
ElseIf wkday = 4 Then
    rNo = Cells(nRow, 11).Value
ElseIf wkday = 5 Then
    rNo = Cells(nRow, 12).Value
ElseIf wkday = 6 Then
    rNo = Cells(nRow, 13).Value
ElseIf wkday = 7 Then
    rNo = Cells(nRow, 14).Value
End If

NDScell = Cells(rNo, 5)
Overcell = Cells(rNo, 6)
Lesscell = Cells(rNo, 7)
CMPcell = Cells(rNo, 12)
RTNcell = Cells(rNo, 13)
SupportNDScell = Cells(rNo, 16)
SupportMatchingcell = Cells(rNo, 17)
SupportHRScell = Cells(rNo, 18)
NDS = UserForm1.txtNDS
Over = UserForm1.txtOver
Less = UserForm1.txtLess
CMP = UserForm1.txtCMP
RTN = UserForm1.txtRTN
SupportNDS = UserForm1.txtSupportNDS
SupportMatching = UserForm1.txtSupportMatching
SupportHRS = UserForm1.txtSupportHRS

If NDS > 0 Then
    Sheets(sht).Select
    NDScell.Value = NDS
    Overcell.Value = Over
    Lesscell.Value = Less
    CMPcell.Value = CMP
    RTNcell.Value = RTN
    SupportNDScell.Value = SupportNDS
    SupportMatchingcell.Value = SupportMatching
    SupportHRScell.Value = SupportHRS
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Was it you who designs the above code? You cannot firstly use variables and  Declare them after that.. Then how to try giving them a value using other undeclared variables (NDS, Over, less etc.)? Your code does  not even try doing what you ask in your question...

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried to rebuild this code and still doesn't work. Now it throws Object variable or With block variable not set. Debugger stops at the line where I want to assign range to datesheet range